# PhoneGap Sencha Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, cordova, sencha-touch

I'm having a hard time creating a project that allows me to run sencha touch on a blackberry using phonegap

I can run a phonegap example,

I can run sencha touch in IOS and a webbrowser but I can't figure out how to link everything together.

I'm using ant and I'm completely new to it I have no idea how to modify PhoneGap sample to include sencha touch

anybody can help me with this set up ?

Cheers

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I anwser this question in the google group of Phonegap:
http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/3bddd6fd63e2ca88

Good Luck!